# Best way to use Subversion as a project communication tool?

Tags: svn, wiki, communication

If the only server allowed for a project was a Subversion (svn) server, what would be the best way to use it as a project communication tool?  For example, is there a good way that it could be used as a wiki, bug tracker, and/or blogging platform?

Note: the server is hosted by Apache, and has the basic html interface.

Answer (score 5):

Subversion is a version control system, in order to have the features you ask, you will have to use a third party add-on, I recommend you to try [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), it's an open source project management and bug tracking system for software development projects and is very easy to integrate with Subversion.

It gives you:

- Project management features
- Online repository browsing
- Wiki
- Ticket System

Check this [demo site](http://www.hosted-projects.com/trac/TracDemo/Demo).

Comment: That's a bit vague; the wording implies that Trac is some sort of add-on that sits atop Subversion, which is not true, it's a separate product which incorporates a wiki and issue tracker, and which integrates with version control.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion is great at what it does, and what it does is version source code, although it'll work well enough for other text-based formats, and binaries, with reduced capabilities.

However, as a one-stop project management tool, it falls rather short of the mark; it's far easier to track and organise bug reports and feature requests in a product that's designed to do that. Likewise, it's also far easier to use an actual wiki engine as a documentation wiki.

If you're looking for something fairly compact, you might consider [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), as has been mentioned elsewhere, which is a decent little issue tracker/wiki/project planning tool with good source control integration.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it or come up with some bad scheme to use svn as a communications tool.  Use some other wiki - there are tons out there and wherever you are hosting your svn you can put a wiki.  I second Trac, by the way.  It will integraee nicely with svn.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is a file versioning control system strictly.  Not a project tool.  I guess you could use it to store project files in certain directories (e.g. project plan), but it is not ideal by any means.